# Birkas HaLevana in Shabbos Clothing

Tags: kiddush-levanah

I recall seeing a Shiltei HaGiborim who writes that one who recites Birkas HaLevana during the weekday, should first don his Shabbos clothing.

Does anyone know where this Shiltei HaGaborim is? 
What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 4):

This idea long predates the Shiltei Hagiborim. Masechet Soferim 19:10 says that this blessing should be recited on Saturday night when you are wearing your nice clothes.

> ואין מברכין על הירח אלא במוצאי שבת כשהוא מבושם ובכלים נאים

[R. Meir Hakohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_HaKohen) writes in Hagahot Maimoniot (Hilchot Berachot 10:16) that based on this his teacher [[R. Meir of Rothenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_of_Rothenburg)] would don his honorable clothes when saying it during the week.

> וכן נהג מורי רבינו שיחיה כשהוא מקדים לברך בחול כדי שלא יעבור זמן הברכה שהוא י"ו בחדש אז לבש סרבל מכובד אשר לו

This is cited in Terumat Hadeshen ([#35](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1835&pgnum=21)) and codified by R. Moshe Isserles in Shulchan Aruch ([O.C. 426:2](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2141)). The reason for this is presumably based on the fact that the Talmud ([Sanhedrin 42a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=42&format=pdf)) says that this is akin to greeting the Divine Presence.

Mishnah Berurah ([426:7](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60389&st=&pgnum=190)), citing earlier *acharonim*, writes that we are no longer careful about this.

Comment: They write this reason?

Comment: @AviM I don't think explicitly.

Comment: Also Maharach Or Zarua 19